# "These sort of things": is it grammatical? (2,670,000 hits on Google) | Does reopening my question seem justified, and will you help me do it?

Tags: discussion

Considering that Peter Shor said:

'Except that it's not an exact duplicate. This question deals with "these kind of X", with a plural determinant and a singular word from kind/type/sort, and those questions deal with "this kind" or "these kinds".'

and Janus Bahs Jaquet said:

'This is decidedly not a duplicate of the question it’s been marked as a duplicate of. It’s a completely different question, and none of the answers in the dupe (or the related questions in Matt’s comment) address this question.'

why is the question

["These sort of things": is it grammatical? (2,670,000 hits on Google)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70341/these-sort-of-things-is-it-grammatical-2-670-000-hits-on-google)

closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Have you tried directly asking either of the two moderators who closed the question (back in 2012)? I would happily vote to reopen your question on the strength of the opinions expressed by Peter Shor and Janus Bahs Jaquet (both of whom I have a lot of respect for as well-informed participants at this site)—but you don't explicitly ask readers here to vote to reopen the question, and only the two mods who closed the question can reasonably be expected to know **why** they closed the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sven No, I asked nothing because just I ask anything to them the only answer I get is 'You are suspended"

Comment: That seems rather harsh of them. In any case, i don't think anyone else can speak for them and their rationale for closing your question even half so well as they themselves can. But again, if you were to edit your question to ask something like, "Does reopening my question seem justified, and will you help me do it?" I would indeed vote to reopen it.

Comment: Tis now open ...

Comment: The whole question is bogus -- you only get 396,000 hits on Google -- noise level.

Comment: It was *you*! I only discovered by chance that your account has been suspended for voting irregularities. I didn't think it was you at all, My my, you must be festering now. Not my fault, it's all your own doing. Pity because in the end you were finally awarding the bounties.

Comment: Downvote my old answers or questions on ELL and I will report you. Make no mistake on that. And it looks like you also had a sockpuppet account. which would explain why one user was "removed" on March 2.